# how to design a layout in html for dashboard

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML and I have given a task for creating a dashboard with following design[image: creating as dashboard like this and I have to add widgets in that place]

can any body help me in designing this HTML page.I have tried jsfiddle and w3 schools I came across about div and tables but I come across about different height and width in HTML

Comment: Welcome to SO. **This is a programming forum, we are here to help you troubleshoot or help you in the codes you provide.** Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to post questions. There are a lot of courses (free and paid) online that will teach you how to use Photoshop.

Comment: hi syfer, nice to hear back,i can understand the answer but the thing Is as I do not kinow how to do this in html I have placed a question in the stcak overflow, as this is the programmers forum, im trying to ask for one programmer to another.

Comment: Disregard my question about designing and please post your code so someone can help you then. We are here to help out in code and not to do full coding.